# Как можно получить данные из предыдущего шага pipe gulp?

Tags: строки, файлы, pipes

Разбираюсь с `gulp` и его `pipe`. Нашел текст в файле с помощью модуля `gulp-find`:

```
let { src, dest } = require("gulp"),
    gulp = require("gulp"),
    find = require (gulp-find);

gulp.task ('task', ()=>{
return src('path/to/file')
.pipe(find(/([`"'])\S+?\.(css|js)\1/gi))
.pipe (console.log(/*то что получили на предыдущем шаге*/))
})
```

Как мне теперь вывести все найденные строки в консоль или массив через `pipe`?

Answer (score 0):

```
const {src, dest, task} = require(`gulp`);
const find = require(`gulp-find`);
const es = require(`event-stream`);

const action = es => es.map((file, cb) => {
    console.log(file.path);
    return cb();
});

task(`task`, () =>
    src(`path/to/file`)
        .pipe(find(/([`"'])\S+?\.(css|js)\1/gi))
        .pipe(action(es)));
```